# Postman: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, flask

I am using Postman to test the Flask server I built following @codebasics ML project videos. However, when I made a POST request, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelwork/.conda/envs/server.py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/michaelwork/.conda/envs/server.py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/michaelwork/.conda/envs/server.py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/michaelwork/.conda/envs/server.py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/michaelwork/.conda/envs/server.py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/michaelwork/.conda/envs/server.py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/michaelwork/Taipei-Real-Estate-Project/server/server.py", line 18, in predict_home_price
    land_shifting = float(request.args.get('land shifting total area'))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here's my code for the Flask server:

```
@app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_home_price():
    location = request.values.get('location')
    land_shifting = float(request.values.get('land shifting total area'))
    num_building = int(request.values.get('num_building'))
    num_land = int(request.values.get('num_land'))
    num_garage = int(request.values.get('num_garage'))
    total_floor_num = int(request.values.get('total floor number'))
    complete_year = int(request.values.get('complete year'))
    compartment = int(request.values.get('compartment'))
    manage_org = int(request.values.get('management org'))
    carpark_price = float(request.values.get('carpark total price'))
    main_building_area = float(request.values.get('main building area'))
    subsidiary_building_area = float(request.values.get('subsidiary building area'))
    balcony_area = float(request.values.get('balcony area'))
    elevator = int(request.values.get('elevator'))
    unit_ntd = int(request.values.get('unit ntd'))
    room_num = int(request.values.get('num_room'))

    response = jsonify({
        'estimated_price': util.get_estimated_price(location, land_shifting, num_building, num_land, num_garage, total_floor_num, complete_year, compartment, manage_org, carpark_price, main_building_area, subsidiary_building_area, balcony_area, elevator, unit_ntd, room_num)
    })

    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response
```

I have tried different methods of **request**, for example,

```
request.form['land shifting total area']
```

and

```
request.args.get('land shifting total area')
```

but all returned the same error. I do not know what I did wrong here. Please help. Thank you in advance!

(This is my first time posting a question on stack overflow, if the format is bad or the question I post is unclear, please forgive me. Thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

I would take two approaches :

the first is a workaround to make your code work, before each conversation add a check that the value is not none
for example :

```
if request.values.get('land shifting total area')==None:
    land_shifting =None
else:
    land_shifting = float(request.values.get('land shifting total area'))
```

As I wrote this is a work around, since you didnt share the source of the data and if None is a valid value , you need to logically check you data source

Comment: Thank you Nir! The data is actually from Kaggle "2020_Real_Estate_Transaction_Records_Taipei_City". 
The goal of the project is to implement a machine learning model that I trained using the data, and predict the price of a house, given the variables (location, land_shifting, and etc...), and build up a website for it. So, None is not a valid value since all variables should have a value.

Comment: So next step if to put a break point when you get the response of the request, my assumption base on the fact that you get values on the rest, is one of two : misspell of the return name in your code('land shifting total area') compare to how it is written in the response or something is wrong in your code logic and it does return None